# Ruby variables' visibility

Tags: ruby

If I declare `@var` in Ruby, every object of that class would have its own `@var`.

But what if I miss `@`? I mean, I declare a variable called `var2` without `@`. Do they share the variable or it is temporarily created?

Comment: What do you mean by 'if I miss @'?

Comment: I mean, if I create a variable called "var2" without @.

Comment: You don't "declare" variables in Ruby...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When variable is declared without scope prefix (`@` - instance, `@@` - class or `$` - global) then is declared for current scope, i.e:

```
class Foo
  def boo
    @boo ||= 'some value'
    var ||= 40

    puts "boo: #@boo var: #{var}"
  end

  def foo
    var ||= 50

    puts "boo: #@boo var: #{var}"
  end
end

c = Foo.new
c.boo # => boo: some value var: 40
c.foo # => boo: some value var: 50

def foo
  $var ||= 30

  puts "$var: #$var"
end

foo # => $var: 30

puts "$var: #$var" # => $var: 30

%w[some words].each do |word|
  lol = word # blocks introduce new scope
end

puts lol # => NameError: undefined local variable or method `lol'

for word in %w[some words]
  lol = word # but for loop not
end

puts lol # => words
```

Answer (score 5):

Without an `@` it's discarded when the method it's in is done running.

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @bing = 123
    zing  = 456
  end

  def get_bing
    @bing
  end

  def get_zing
    zing
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.get_bing #=> 123
foo.get_zing #=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `zing' for #<Foo:0x10b535258 @bing=123>
```

This shows that an instance variable `@bing` is saved with that instance.  It's value is accessible within any method on that instance.

But a local variable `zing` is not persisted (in most cases), and as soon as the method is done running any local variables are discarded, and no longer accessible.  When `get_zing` is run, it looks for a local variable or method named `zing` and doesn't find one, because the `zing` from `initialize` is long gone.

Answer (score 1):

It will become a local variable that belongs to the local lexical scope.

Ex.

```
class Foo
  def Bar
    @fooz = 1
  end
  def Barz
    fooz = 2
  end
  def test
    puts @fooz
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.Bar
f.test
f.Barz
f.test
```

Output:

```
1
1 #not 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a variable called `var2` it is local and is only in scope in the construct where it is declared. That is:

- If you declared it within a method, it will be local to that method.
- If you try to declare within a class definition but outside any method, it will raise a NameError. For example:

> ```
> class Foo
>   bar = 2    
> end
>
> Foo.new
>
> NameError: undefined local variable or method 'bar'
> ```