# Tricky Ruby scoping issue

Tags: ruby

Why does this little snippet of Ruby code not work?

```
cached = {}
def cache(*key)
  cached[key.join] ||= yield
end
cache("key") do "value" end
```

I get the following error:

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `cached' for main:Object

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the instance variable instead of local:

```
@cached = {}
def cache(*key)
  @cached[key.join] ||= yield
end
```

You can not use local `cached` variable inside your cache method, because local variables not exist outside the method definition, so if you didnt define local variable in method body or method params earlier, Ruby can not find it.
More about variables visibility [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123868/ruby-variables-visibility).

Comment: Haha, wow, brainfart... You're right, thanks!

Comment: The question is, why code is not working? and not how to make it work ?

Comment: Added reason explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to complement @ProgNoob answer.

If you come from languages like `C` or `C++` where a scope is created using a block of code.

```
{
   ....
}
```

And all local variables inside that scope are not visible outside, but they are visible in each scope created inside, for example:

```
{
  int a = 3;
  {
     // a is visible inside here
  }
  // a is visible inside here
  ...
}
// a is not visible outside the scope
```

Ruby does not handle things the same way. When you create a `class`, `module` or a `method` you are creating a whole new scope, not getting anything from upper scopes, like we saw in `C`.

```
v0 = 0
class SomeClass # Scope gate
  v1 = 1      
  # only v1 is visible here

  def some_method # Scope gate
    v2 = 2
    # only v2 is visible here        
  end # end of def scope gate
end # end of class scope gate
```

To break the scope gates:

- class definitions with with `Class.new`
- module definitions with `Module.new`
- method definitions with `define_method`

Previous example without scope gates

```
v0 = 0
SomeClass = Class.new do
  v1 = 1
  # v0 and v1 visible here

  define_method(:some_method) do
    v2 = 2
    # v0, v1 and v2 visible here
  end
end
# v0 only visible here
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. My issue was I was using the variable inside of a block like `foo = {}; whatever do (here I use foo) end` but then later when I tried to use it inside the method it was undefined. I see my mistake now.